Is it possible for a Small Cavalier to have a mature, Medium mount?
This is a follow up on this question.
I noticed that Goblins have an ancestry feat that would allow them to get a Medium Wolf as a Cavalier, but it seems like at maturity, the Wolf would become Large.
Is there any way for a Small Cavalier to get a mature, Medium mount? Per Pathfinder Society rules, if possible.

Wolf starts small, for reference https://2e.aonprd.com/AnimalCompanions.aspx?ID=83

@WeirdFrog yes, but Cavalier contains a specific exception to that, because Cavalier companions are always mounts.

You have to get a new wolf *
Your original wolf has to start Medium, so that you can ride on it (Cavalier Dedication makes this possible). When it becomes Mature, it has to increase to Large.
However, after taking the Impressive Mount feat, if your wolf happens to die, you can get a new wolf, which will be increased in size by Mature, because it is mandatory, but the change from Cavalier Dedication is optional:

if the animal usually starts as Small, you can begin with a Medium version of that animal (changing no statistics other than its size).

So it will be Medium, just what you need. All the follow-up feats from Cavalier are talking about a mount not "the mount you gained from the Dedication".
Cavalier dedication says:

You must choose an animal companion that's at least one size larger than you

When you replace your Mature wolf, you do chose an
animal companion that is larger than you.

*) I see no way for this to work without the Rough Rider feat

I don't know that what you're describing works RAW. You'd originally start with a Medium wold, to match the restrictions on the dedication. If that wolf were to die, surely you'd have to replace it with another Medium/Large companion with the mount trait. If you tried to replace it with a Small bird, for example, that seems clearly illegal. Likewise, I think a Small wolf would also be an illegal pick, even if it would become Medium due to another feat.

I'm also not sure it works, but Andras idea is that, once you have the Feat that increases their Size (not the default 'may start as Medium' from the Dedication), you could replace it with a 'small' wolf that is now Mature and therefore Medium.

Also, if this is for a home game, talk to your GM about handwaving the size increase away. If its for PFS, I think getting a new Companion is just a Downtime thing you can do, but I don't play Organized so I can't certify that without some research

@Bagley, it is not illegal to call a Medium wolf, see my edit

My intuition is that you'd pick a companion to replace your previous wolf, then apply the feat that makes that companion mature. (So you'd have to pick a Medium wolf again.) Your edit implies that one picks a companion and applies the feat to make them mature simultaneously. Is there a parallel somewhere else in the rules to clarify which approach is right? (Maybe that should be a new question?)

That concern is why I haven't +1'd ha. I haven't had to go through a Companion replacement yet.
